# If I see a good question on another site should I ask here to create a better catalogue of questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've read this [article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) about answering your own questions and it's actively encouraged.

I'm wondering is it OK to copy questions from other sites and ask them here even if the question already has a satisfactory answer?

It would mean there would be a better collection of question and answers here but it might be seen as trying to find any easy way to get rep.

What's the consensus on such actions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers relate to copyright issues from poaching from other (non stackoverflow) sites.  This is good advice, but I thought I would add a comment about the situation about copying from other stackoverflow sites as that was how I interpreted the question.

I do not believe there are any copyright issues when using content from another s.e. site as I would be pretty sure that everything we contribute is owned by stack-exchange (if it is not otherwise infringing someone else's copyright).  However I would be pretty sure that blatant copying or cross posting of identical questions would be frowned upon.

You might see a question on (say) sci-fi and fantasy, and think that you might want to get an opinion from the community here - I would not think it unreasonable to expect you to ask that question in a different way and not just to copy the material.

But the purpose of repeating a question here would be to try to get a different answer from a movie perspective.  If the answer on sci-fi was perfectly good, I don't see any reason why you should repeat the question here.

Comment: +1 for Movies opinion vs. SciFi, but asking in a different way + if a question elsewhere is good, no need to repeat here.

Answer (score 7):

Just like what was stated it is mostly due to copyright that this is discouraged. Besides, I'd rather a lot of personal user generated contenet than blatant copies from other sites.

Thats not to say that using these items as reference to your own blogoverflow, or whatever but it should be far from a blatant copy.

Answer (score 6):

We have had problems with new and inexperienced members early in the beta who were detected poaching questions from other sites. It was considered problematic especially for copyright reasons. Those questions were closed and deleted, and the accounts were closed, if I recall correctly.

I don't believe the catalogue benefit warrants the legal problems we would be exposed to.

While the intention probably doesn't involve plagarism, a careful reading of this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/dealing-with-posts-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources) from meta.stackoverflow.com will clarify positions.

Comment: I can see why there would be copyright issues when taking questions from other sites, but what about seeing a question on Facebook or other social media sites? Should I just give them a link to this site so they can ask themselves or ask on their behalf?