# Questions from other platforms?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There are other platforms (like YouTube, Quora, etc..) where people discuss about movies and ask questions.

If I found a question on any of these site about a movie and I couldn't find any answers for that question, then is it OK I post the question here?

Then do I have to add any extra comment or reference?

Comment: Yes you can ask those question with "reference" and maybe better if you mention why answer there are not satisfying.

Comment: Related: [Repost of Questions from Other Sites](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/998/27264)

Comment: Content on other sites is very likely to be copyrighted material.  Please don't copy content into a post on this site .... but asking the same question in your own words is fine.